# Looping through a 2D array and searching for a certain value, then printing out an element

Tags: java, arrays

So I want to search a 2D array whose index's sum is 0, then print out an element from that array index. Then I want to go through the array again, and find the index's sum is 1 then print out an element from that array index, and so on...

For example:

```
0 = array[0][0] = apple

1 = array[0][1] = banana
1 = array[1][0] = coffee

2 = array[2][0] = danish
2 = array[1][1] = eggs
2 = array[0][2] = fish

and so on
```

The only thing is that I am not sure how to go about looping through this. This is for a homework assignment, so I would appreciate some help on how to go about solving this.

**Please do not spoon feed me the answer, I would prefer a tip or a hint in order to learn .**

---

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            sum = i + j;
            System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
        }
    }
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
sum: 0
sum: 1
sum: 2
sum: 3  
sum: 1
sum: 2
sum: 3
sum: 4
sum: 2
sum: 3
sum: 4
sum: 5
```

Comment: Are you asking how to print out the sum of the indexes for each element in the array while also printing out what the array contains at those two indexes?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to iterate through a 2D array, searching for a pair of indices that add up to 0, output the value stored at those indices, iterate, searching for a pair of indices that add up to 1, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you generate all pairs integers that sum up to another integer? For example, given `sum = 5`, can you come up with a loop that churns out (0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 0)?

Comment: I want to find the sum associated with the index, and then print out the array at the index associated with the sum. But I want to do it in numeric order. For example, I want to search where the sum is equal to  0, print, then go on to the sums equal to 1, print, then go on to the sums equal to 2, and print, and so on.

Comment: @Bovine yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ill give you some hints.

**Hint #1:** You don't have to iterate through the array.

**Hint #2:** The number you guessing lets say `3`. Will always be the highest number that can be added to create the sum.

- `3` is the max
- `0` is always the min.

**Hint #3:** think of this problem as a computation problem between `i` and `j` then accessing the array.

---

If you want the actual answer or more hints let me know :D

Comment: Good answer. Plus rather efficient solution.

Comment: @user3718441 I recommend this answer. It leads to the most efficient solution, and has the additional benefit of being the one answer here that doesn't straight up give you an algorithm =p

Comment: @progenhard could you tell me why the person does not need to iterate thorough the array? I asked for my learning goal

Comment: @KickButtowski Well. It some degree you do. To print out the values. However, This is a computation problem without giving away too much. Once you get the values, `(0,0)` for `0` or `(0,1)(1,0)` for `1`... you will have to print out those list of _positions_ that you have computed.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `sum` values first, from `0` through `numRows + numColumns - 2` (the sum of the maximum possible indices).

Inside this loop, loop through possible row values with `i`.  Calculate the column value `j` by subtracting `i` from `sum`.

If the indices `i` and `j` are valid, then access the array and print the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about time complexity, you can just use an if-statement.

```
for(int k=0; k<MaxSum; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            sum = i + j;
            if(sum == k) {
                System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can do it in `O(n)` and you don't even need to iterate through the entire two-dimensional array.</s> Finding the set of indices that add up to a certain sum can be done in `O(n)` time. But finding all indices for all-possible values of `x` will take `O(n^2)`.

Let's think about what you want to do. We can start by making the observation that in a two-dimensional array `A` of dimensions `m x n`, you want to find all `i`, and `j`, that sum up to a particular value `x` as long as `x` is lesser than or equal to `m + n - 2` (since the highest you can access is `A[m - 1][n - 1]` with the added constraint that `i < m` and `j < n`.

Now think of the different ways you can generate a value `x` by summing up two different values `i` and `j`. What possible values can `i` and `j` take? For example, if `x` is `7`, `i` can be `0` and `j` can be `7`, or vice-versa. You can also have `i` as `6` and `j` as `1` and vice-versa. Think about how you would generate a set of such values. You need to keep in mind, however, that all such pairs you generate will not be valid. You have the added constraint that `i` and `j` need to fit within the dimensions of your array.

Comment: Wouldn't this still be `O(n^2)` You will have to iterate between 0..array.length. This is also isn't this assuming boths sides are the same length? :o

Comment: No, it won't be `O(n^2)`. You iterate from `0` to `x` and build up your list of values while ensuring that `i < m` and `j < n`. Then you iterate over your list of computed values and grab elements out of the 2d array. Or, you can simply access values as you are computing the indices. Is there anything I'm missing? :) I may have done this wrong :p

Comment: @progenhard Ahh, I see what you are saying. He wants to loop through **all** possible values of `x`! Yes, in that case it will be `O(n^2)`. I thought he simply wanted all indices for a given value of `x`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: You don't even need to store the values you can probably just print in place. It's one of those ACM problem type things you're thinking more actual code. However, awesome alg its pretty much along the lines of what i came up with.